# Does this produce a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm following a book on C++ programming, and I'm following the exercises. One exercise asks me to create a program that produces a memory leak. Will this program produce such a leak?

```
int main()
{
    int * pInt =  new int;
    *pInt = 20;

    pInt = new int;
    *pInt =50;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the memory will most likely be reclaimed really soon after. Something just looping and leaking some memory every second or so is more of a problem. Taking a GDI example, not destroying a brush you create in your window repainting handler.

Comment: Wow, a six-way tie for most upvoted answer at two each. That's got to be some kind of record.

Comment: ha! It might just well be.

Comment: @chris: given all memory is reclaimed when the program terminates that's trivially true for the example code, but if some long-running processing kicked in after the second `new` the memory would remain unclaimed for as long a time.  The severity is a product of the amount of memory per leak, how often it happens, and whether memory intensive operations or limits make that problematic afterwards (due to exhaustion, swapping, fragmentation etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> One exercise asks me to create a program that produces a memory leak.
> ```
>
> Will this program produce such a leak?
>
> an utter exercise , and your code is a  better answer to exercise !

Pointers and memory leaks. These are truly the items that consume most of the debugging time for developers

### *Memory leak*

Memory leaks can be really annoying. The following list describes some scenarios that result in memory leaks.

```
Reassignment,  I'll use an example to explain reassignment.

char *memoryArea = malloc(10);
char *newArea = malloc(10);
```

This assigns values to the memory locations shown in Figure 4 below.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-toughgame/fig4.gif
    Figure 4. Memory locations

memoryArea and newArea have been allocated 10 bytes each and their respective contents are shown in Figure 4. If somebody executes the statement shown below (pointer reassignment )

```
memoryArea = newArea;
```

then it will surely take you into tough times in the later stages of this module development.

In the code statement above, the developer has assigned the memoryArea pointer to the newArea pointer. As a result, the memory location to which memoryArea was pointing to earlier becomes an orphan, as shown in Figure 5 below. It cannot be freed, as there is no reference to this location. This will result in a memory leak of 10 bytes.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-toughgame/fig5.gif
    Figure 5. Memory leak

```
Before assigning the pointers, make sure memory locations are not becoming orphaned.
Freeing the parent block first

Suppose there is a pointer memoryArea pointing to a memory location of 10 bytes. The third byte of this memory location further points to some other dynamically allocated memory location of 10 bytes, as shown in Figure 6.
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-toughgame/fig6.gif
    Figure 6. Dynamically allocated memory

```
free(memoryArea)
```

**If memoryArea is freed by making a call to free, then as a result the newArea pointer also will become invalid. The memory location to which newArea was pointing cannot be freed, as there is no pointer left pointing to that location. In other words, the memory location pointed by newArea becomes an orphan and results in memory leak.

Whenever freeing the structured element, which in turn contains the pointer to dynamically allocated memory location, first traverse to the child memory location (newArea in the example) and start freeing from there, traversing back to the parent node.
    The correct implementation here will be:
    free( memoryArea->newArea);
    free(memoryArea);
    Improper handling of return values
    At time, some functions return the reference to dynamically allocated memory. It becomes the responsibility of the calling function to keep track of this memory location and handle it properly.**

```
char *func ( )
{
        return malloc(20); // make sure to memset this location to â€˜\0â€™â€¦
}

void callingFunc ( )
{
        func ( ); // Problem lies here
}

In the example above, the call to the func() function inside the callingFunc() function is not handling the return address of the memory location. As a result, the 20 byte block allocated by the func() function is lost and results in a memory leak.
```

Sharp Reference at :
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-toughgame/

**Update:**
your interest let me for an edit

### **Simple rules to avoid Memory Leaks in C**

You are allocating memory for p and q:

```
p=new int [5];
/* ... */
q=new int;
```

But you are only freeing p using an invalid operator, since arrays should be deleted using delete[]. You should at some point free both p and q using:

```
delete[] p;
delete q;
```

Note that since you are making your pointers point to the other pointer's allocated buffer, you might have to check which delete operator corresponds to which new operation.

You should use delete[] on the buffer allocated with new[] and delete with the buffer allocated with new.

> Rule 1: Always write “free” just after “malloc”

```
int *p = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * n );

free (p);
```

> Rule 2: Never, ever, work with the allocated pointer. Use a copy!

```
int *p_allocated = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * n );

int *p_copy = p_allocated;

// do your stuff with p_copy, not with p_allocated!

// e.g.:

while (n--) { *p_copy++ = n; }

...

free (p_allocated);
```

> Rule 3: Don’t be parsimonious. Use more memory.

Always start by allocating more memory than you need.  After you finish debugging, go back and cut on memory use. If you need an array 1000 integers long, allocate 2000, and only after you make sure everything else is OK – only then go back and cut it down to 1000.

> Rule 4: Always carry array length along with you

Wherever your array goes, there should go with it it’s length. A nice trick is to allocate an array sized n+1, and save n into it’s 0 place:

```
int *p_allocated = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * (n+1) );
int *p_copy = p_allocated+1;
p_copy[-1] = n;
// do your stuff with p_copy, not with p_allocated!
free (p_allocated);
```

> Rule 5: Be consistent. And save comments

The most important thing is to be consistent and to write down what you do. I am always amazed at how many programmers seem to think that comments are a waste of time. They are imperative. Without comments, you probably won’t remember what you did. Imagine returning to your code a year after you wrote it, and spending  countless hour trying to recall what that index does. Better to spend a couple of seconds writing it down.

Also, if you are consistent, you will not fail often. Always use the same mechanism for passing arrays and pointers. Don’t change the way you do things lightly. If you decide to use my previous trick, use it everywhere, or you might find yourself referring back to a nonexistent place because you forgot what type of reference you chose.

Ref : http://mousomer.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/simple-rules-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-c/

Comment: This is the best explanation, thank you. I now have a better understanding of memory and memory leaks, and finally learned what malloc and free was for.

Answer (score 5):

Considering it is a trivial example, not having a `delete` paired with your `new` is a leak. In order to prevent a leak in this case you would need the following:

```
int * pInt =  new int;
*pInt = 20;

delete pInt ;

pInt = new int;
*pInt =50;

delete pInt ;
```

A decent tool to use to detect memory leaks is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). I ran the tool on your sample code, like so:

```
 valgrind ./a.out
```

and this is part of the output it produced:

```
==14153== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14153==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==14153==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==14153== 
==14153== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14153==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
```

Which confirms that indeed the program does leak memory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  To avoid leaks, every time you call `new`, you have to have a matching call to `delete`.  You have 2 calls to `new` and no calls to `delete`, so you have 2 leaks.

Note that when your program exits, the OS will free up all the memory you've allocated with `new`.  So memory leaks are really only a problem for non-trivial programs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this produces not one, but two memory leaks: both allocated `int`s are leaked. Moreover, the first one is leaked irrecoverably: once you assign `pInt` a `new int` the second time, the first allocated item is gone forever.

Comment: Would compiler optimization settings affect this answer? None of the code has any visible side effects, so it might get optimized away?

Comment: @JBentley Yes, that's what's going to happen at the high optimization levels. Moreover, the memory will be given back to OS anyway. However, logically there are two leaks there, even though it may not happen in hardware.

Comment: Agreed. Worth noting anyway, in case the OP tries to produce code that demonstrates a memory leak at runtime, and wonders why it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this program produce suck a leak?

Yes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. When pInt is overwritten with a new int pointer, you lose that memory that was previously allocated, however when the program returns, most modern operating systems will clean up this memory, as well as the memory lost by not deallocating pInt at the end.

So in essence, yes, something like this will result in two memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

It does, because you allocate space with the statement "new int", but do not use "delete" to free the space.

Comment: Just what I had thought to begin with. I'm sort of a noob when it comes to memory management and pointers, so it's kind of weird for me.

Comment: Memory management is hard when we start, but gets easier after some coding. When I was a student, I tried allocating memory within a loop until the program stops, to measure the amount of memory available to the program. It worked :o)

Comment: @HenryOrrin, It's a lot less to worry about if you choose not to worry about it and employ RAII instead (like in the below comment).

Comment: @HenryOrrin It's also worth mentioning that in real code you'll nearly always try to avoid doing memory management yourself with `new` and `delete`, instead using data structures that take care of it for you (e.g. `std::list` or `std::vector`), or smart pointers.

Comment: @chris What's RAII? Forgive my foolishness ^_^;

Comment: @HenryOrrin, Foolishness not, it's not something you hear about when being assigned something like this. Sample applications of it are in JBentley's comment. It's the idiom for using something that automatically manages the resource (including allocated memory) instead of you having to manage it. For example, a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr` in this case) calls `delete ptr;` (by default and slightly simplified) when the smart pointer object goes out of scope. Other than that, it works just like a pointer. [More reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: @HenryOrrin, those were the old days when we ran Borland C++ on MS-DOS machines. We were doing an undergraduate assignment, and noted that our C++ programs can use much less memory than the computer actually had. So we wrote something like the code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hlo8sp9vzkoiid/main.cpp):

Then we found out that the compiler had a "memory model" setting that limited the amount of memory available to the program :o).

Comment: @Totoro Oh I see, so basically Borland C++ determined how much memory the program would be able to use instead of that being done by the OS?

Comment: @HenryOrrin, Yes. I guess this was necessary because of memory management issues of MS DOS 5 on different 80x86 processors. Such problems disappeared with the advent of 32 and 64-bit operating systems.